# Transition not occurring first time

Tags: css, transform, transition, translate3d

I have the following css:

```
.some-el {
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  top: 0%;
  background-color: black;

  /* All vendor-prefixes */
  transition: transform linear 1s;
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

.some-el.open {
  /* All vendor-prefixes */
  transform: translate3d(0,0%,0);
}
```

With this html:

```
  <div class="some-el"></div>
  <a id="open" href="#">Toggle</a>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('open').onclick = function() {
      document.querySelector('.some-el').classList.toggle('open');
    };
  </script>
```

The first time I click the link there is no transition, but on all subsequent clicks (whether to open or to close) the transition does occur.

Comment: no transition either way, see [a demo based on your code](http://jsfiddle.net/ab73m/1/).

Answer (score 0):

The transition is not working at all for me using the above code. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jessekinsman/4d9Pu/1/).

However, I think if you change your transition to all, like so

```
transition: all linear 1s;
```

That should work. I got it working in this fiddle
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jessekinsman/d3Csm/1/)